# React Client post request uploading image?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-cli

I am trying to upload an image from my react client to a backend api server, which has an endpoint parameters defined as:

file: string($base64)
(formdata)

open api file example shows : Example : U3dhZ2dlciByb2Nrcw==

I'm using OpenApi TypeScript generator CLI which generates all the endpoint functions for me, and its expecting the endpoint file to be a string?

Is the open api generator CLI wrong? Am I suppose to send FormData as payload?

or am I suppose to send string base64 as payload?